# Why is my code not running my "diceplace1" funtion?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, graphics

I am trying to make a dice rolling simulator where every 3 seconds it rolls the dice again, and prints the image.

I've tried a lot of different things, but the closest I've gotten is it rolling the dice once, or rolling the dice but not displaying the image. Does anyone see any errors with my code?

With the code below, the dice is rolled every 3 seconds, but the images aren't displayed.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import os
import time
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import ttk

dicelist = []
diceamount = 1
game = True
root = Tk()


def diceplace1(dicelist):
    if dicelist == 1:
        diceimage = Image.open('dice1.png')
        resized_image = diceimage.resize((100,100))
        new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
    if dicelist == 2:
        diceimage = Image.open('dice2.png')
        resized_image = diceimage.resize((100,100))
        new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
    if dicelist == 3:
        diceimage = Image.open('dice3.png')
        resized_image = diceimage.resize((100,100))
        new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
    if dicelist == 4:
        diceimage = Image.open('dice4.png')
        resized_image = diceimage.resize((100,100))
        new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
    if dicelist == 5:
        diceimage = Image.open('dice5.png')
        resized_image = diceimage.resize((100,100))
        new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
    if dicelist == 6:
        diceimage = Image.open('dice6.png')
        resized_image = diceimage.resize((100,100))
        new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
    label = Label(root, image = new_image).pack()
            
canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg="#F5F5DC")
canvas.pack()
while True:
    dicelist = []
    for i in range(diceamount):
        dicelist.append(random.randint(1,6))
        print(dicelist)
    diceplace1(dicelist[0])
    time.sleep(3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you have both `dicelist = []`?

Comment: The while loop will block the execution of `root.mainloop()`, so nothing will be shown.  Use *after loop* (using `after()`) instead of while loop.